# Data structure to store program sequence - Python

Tags: python, data-structures

I am writing a software to get sequence of commands from user with standard control flow (i.e user can nest his desired commands) :

```
   cmd1
   cmd2
   cmd3
   loop.1:
    cmd1
    cmd2
    cmd3
      loop.2
        cmd1
        cmd2
      endloop.2
    cmd4
    cmd5
   endloop.1
```

Do you happen to know of a data structure which keeps order in nested structures? Basically, what data structure is used for storing an input program in any language? Do you know the equivalent in Python? I am trying to use `OrderedDict()` but there should be a more customized one.

Answer (score 1):

Use an (indirectly) nested list. I assume you have a class

```
class Command(object):
    def execute(self):
        # whatever
```

for you basic commands. Make a subclass for loops:

```
class Loop(Command):
    def __init__(self, condition, cmds):
        self.body = cmds                  # list of Commands
        self.condition = condition

    def execute(self):
        while self.condition.execute():
            for x in self.body:
                x.execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a binary tree. If you don't want to implement one in python, you could fake an in-order traversal of such a tree and store it in a list.

Answer (score 0):

It's called an [Abstract Syntax Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) (or AST for short).

Which is .. a tree, so it could be modelled as list-of-lists, but you might want to use something with a bit more structure (depends on how "typed" you want your AST to be).

I'd go with having an object for each Node, each having an 'Operation' and zero or more leaves (i.e. sub-expressions or sub-statements).

For a more rigidly typed structure, the # of leaves would be restricted (i.e. use a tuple) for everything except common "blocks", "body" which are just list-of-statements, i.e. function or if/while/for bodies..